# transposing in SAS software

Tags: sas, transpose

just have some problems with transposing data in SAS; in particular, it could be because the year headings are in year format 2013, 2014, etc but have no idea how to resolve it

so for instance-->
sampledata set:

```
CompanyID  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020  2021
1           5.3   3.4   6.4   7.8   5.4   9.8   2.4   4.2   4.2
2           2.3   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...

proc transpose data=sampledata out=long1;
   var 2013-2021;
   by CompanyID;
run;
```

so basically SAS cannot seem to recognise '**2013-2021**' as a variable, what would be the recommendations? thanks!

Comment: What are the actual SAS variable names? They can not start with a number.

Comment: hi, they were uploaded / imported as excel file so in excel, the column names were 2013, 2014, 2015 etc how should one locate the actual SAS variable names? thanks!

Comment: Proc Contents data = YOURDATASET; run;

Comment: Is the source an Excel file (XLS or XLSX) or a TEXT file (like CSV file for example)?  If it is as CSV file then just read it directly into the structure you want.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you could have variables with names like `2013` would be if you had accidentally set the VALIDVARNAME option to ANY.

In that case you need to use NAME LITERALS when referencing names that do not follow the normal rules for names (only contain digits, letters or underscores and do not start with a digit).

```
proc transpose data=sampledata out=long1;
   by CompanyID;
   var '2013'n-'2021'n;
run;
```

If you had imported the data with the VALIDVARNAME option set to V7 then those strings would have been converted into names like _2013, _2014 etc. In which case use

```
var _2013 - _2021 ;
```

Comment: It's likely that it wasn't accidental, but rather was a system default - SAS Studio for example often defaults to `options validvarname=any` and `options validmemname=extend`.

Answer (score 0):

If the data was imported from Excel, the variable **labels** will be the original column headers, but the variable **names** will be the header values transformed to **valid SAS names**, most likely a leading underscore was added.

The following code would work based on the above presumptions.

```
proc transpose data=sampledata out=long1;
   var _2013 - _2021;
   by CompanyID;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS has certain rules about variable names, but there is support for variables that break those rules. SAS handles those through a concept called a name literal. Name literals take the form `'variable'n`. In your case, you just need to specify name literals.

```
proc transpose data=sampledata out=long1;
   var '2013'n-'2021'n;
   by CompanyID;
run;
```